# Alt text of image doesn't appear

Tags: php, mysql

I've trying to put alt text on images but seems to me that doesn't work. Here is how I try

```
// get the info from the db
$sql = "SELECT name, caption, alt FROM images order by id desc LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
  $result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

   // while there are rows to be fetched...
  while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // echo data

  echo "<img src=\"upload/".$list['name']."\" alt=\"".$list['alt']."\" /></a>";
  echo $list['caption'];
```

With image and caption everything is fine. But in the html of the page I didn't see alt text.

update: **var_dump($list)**

```
array (size=3) 'name' => string '3ce08e141493823aeeded14f5dda6573.jpg' (length=36)  
'caption' => string 'image 1' (length=14) 
'alt' => string 'testing alt text 2' (length=18)
```

Comment: Do you have values on your $list['alt']?

Comment: `print_r($list['alt']);`

Comment: `alt` is the text that is displayed when an image in the `src` does not exists on the server. If you want the text to appear when you hover over the image, use `title`

Comment: `print_r($list['alt']);` doesn't return anything. But in my table I have value..

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($list);` ?

Comment: Updated with var_dump($list)

Comment: echo "<img src='upload/".$list['name']."' title='".$list['alt']."' />"; Try this. It will solve parse error if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pl check $list['alt'] is not empty & also set title value, so that you can test properly ...
```

--
Thanks

Comment: Pl accept answer if you get solution. So that others can also get help.

Comment: I will but still is not fixed.

Comment: Ok. Just follow what I say in my answer and you will get solution. Try it.

Comment: `$list['alt']` is not empty you can see on var_dump($list)

Comment: Try: echo "<img src='upload/".$list['name']."' title='".$list['alt']."' />";

Comment: `title=''` empty title. And as I said on localhost work but in public host doesn't work. var_dump doesn't have alt..

Comment: Then try using static value like alt = 'test value' and title = 'test value'. If it is working then your issue solved here.

Comment: `src=\"upload/".$list['name']."\" alt = 'test value' title = 'test value' />` don't have `alt` and `title` in html. Only on localhost

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use `title` because the `alt` text will  be shown in place of the image, any time the image isn't available. `title` will be shown as a tooltip on :hover for any browsers that support that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `title` attribute instead of `alt`. I wonder why there is a trailing `</a>` tag on your `echo`.

The right way...

```
echo "<img src=upload/".$list['name']." title=".$list['alt']."/>";
```

[`Why should I use title attribute ?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872407/1003917)

Comment: I forget to remove `</a>` tag. With title again nothing in the html `<img src="/upload/50cd2bd355291c5c6baf6b686d714c2c.jpg" /><br />`

Comment: Can you try this ? `echo "<img src=upload/".$list['name']." title=".$list['alt']."/>";`

Comment: Now I can see it `<img src="upload/3ce08e141493823aeeded14f5dda6573.jpg" title="testing alt text 2" />`

Comment: But on localhost. When I try in hosting is `title=""` empty title

Comment: Since both databases are different , you may not have the `alt` value on your remote .. Did you check with `var_dump` again ?

Comment: Is not there when I check var_dump `array(2) { ["name"]=> string(36) "db139b1dd0064a5c7a22e0dbfb2f32cb.jpg" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: That is the reason :)

Comment: So what can be the problem with my hosting? Any idea. Public database is version `5.5.36-cll - MySQL` and localhost is `5.6.12-log - MySQL` but I don't thing this is the problem

Comment: If the table does not contain the alt values how do you expect that to print ? Export your database from your localhost and import it inside your remote database and everything will work fine.

Comment: It have alt row in table and it have value. Databases are equal on local and remote.