# Is the title attribute proper with HTML tables or is there a specific solution?

Tags: wordpress, html, html-table, seo, sitemap

I have a WordPress site with several blog posts that have tabular data.  This tabular data is important so I've been looking at building a plugin that would build a sitemap for guests to reference but I'm unsure if there is a proper solution to identifying the name or title of the table.

In research I've read and understand that the [`title` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#the-title-attribute) is a [global attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#sec-global-attributes), which means that you can use it on *all* elements:

```
<table id="foo" class="bar" title="Hello World">

</table>
```

and:

> The `title` attribute represents advisory information for the element,
>   such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. On a link, this could be
>   the title or a description of the target resource; on an image, it
>   could be the image credit or a description of the image; on a
>   paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text; on a
>   citation, it could be further information about the source; on
>   interactive content, it could be a label for, or instructions for, use
>   of the element; and so forth. The value is text.

but I'm also aware that `name` isn't HTML5 compliant after reading [Can we give name to html `<table>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677536/can-we-give-name-to-html-table) but there is `data-name="Hello World"`.

Further research I've looked at:

- [About the Title/Alt attributes;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146115/about-the-title-alt-attributes)
- [HTML img tag: title attribute vs. alt attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872389/html-img-tag-title-attribute-vs-alt-attribute)
- [11 Tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)
- [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

In regards to SEO, HTML5 compliancy and sitemap development what is the proper way to declare the title or name of a table because I'm having issues finding an answer in any schema regarding tables other than using the `title` attribute?

Comment: Can I get an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: "In regards to SEO" … this question is off-topic. Try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "sitemap development" — I have no idea what you mean. Are you talking about sitemap.xml? Or a user facing HTML document describing the important parts of the site? What are you actually trying to achieve by adding markup?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm unsure if there is a proper solution to identifying the name or
>   title of the table.

What you're looking for is the `<caption>` element.

**Working Example:**

```css
table {
width: 500px;
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

caption {
line-height: 32px;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<table>
<caption>I am a table caption</caption>
<thead>
<th>Header Cell</th>
<th>Header Cell</th>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>Data Cell</td>
<td>Data Cell</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Data Cell</td>
<td>Data Cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption

**Excerpt:**

*The HTML `<caption>` element represents the title of a table [...] it is always the first descendant of a `<table>`*

Comment: The caption element modifies the table's content and that isn't something I'm looking to do which was why I was seeking a backend solution since the content is from an automatic post ingestion.  If I didn't want it visible I'd have to build a hack solution of `display: none;`.

Comment: There's nothing hacky about using `display: none` (or, for that matter, `visibility: hidden`, or `opacity: 0`). `<caption>` is an element explicitly and exclusively intended to represent the title of a table. I'm not clear why `<caption>` isn't exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Putting content in a document which you never intend to show anybody is hacky. It's also the poster child of black hat SEO.

Comment: If you never intend to show it to any user-agent at all, then yes, I agree with you, it's hacky. Not displaying an element in a browser viewport - but that element still playing a role within the document structure and available to other user-agents if and when needed - I don't think that's hacky.